# Collapse doesn't work in a Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to use the most basic collapse function inside a Modal but the collapse won't trigger

Literally just copied [this w3schools collapse example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h) into my Modal.

This is my Modal code:

```
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss" ngbModalContainer>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Collapse</h4>
  </div>
  <form>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
      <div id="demo" class="collapse">
            This is the collapsible text!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="open(content)">Open Modal</button>
```

My BasicModalComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'basic-modal',
  templateUrl: './BasicModal.html'
})
export class BasicModalComponent {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

my AppComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<basic-modal></basic-modal>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

My AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [NgbModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, BasicModalComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I tried debugging the behavior of collapse in the DOM, seems like when you collapse a `<div>` it adds it some classes and few attributes, and when collapsing it back it changes them as well.

When I debugged it within the Modal, triggering the collapse button does not manipulate the DOM, the class of the `<div>` and its' attributes remained the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: You problem is located here https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal-window.ts#L57

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for your reply, could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Bootstrap collapse event click handles on document http://take.ms/mAhbw but `ModalWindow` component breaks bubbling via `stopPropagation`

Comment: @yurzui Hmm i see. so what am i supposed to do if i want a collapsible section in my modal?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yout case you can "monkey patch" `ModalWindow` like as described below:

```
open(content) {
    // get reference to NgbModalRef
    let modal: any = this.modalService.open(content);
    modal.result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });

    let cancelPropagation = false;

    // overriding methods of NgbModalWindow 
    Object.assign(modal._windowCmptRef.instance.constructor.prototype, {
        stopPropagation: () => {
          cancelPropagation = true;
        },
        backdropClick: function() {
          if(cancelPropagation) { 
            cancelPropagation = false;
            return;
          }
          if (this.backdrop === true) {
            this.dismiss(ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK);
          }  
        }
    });
  }
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4dysmuKfx9tSwAgmEedp?p=preview)**

But it is very dirty way because it's using private property.

You would use [NgbCollapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse) directive which is part of `ng-bootstrap` package like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
   Simple collapsible
</button>
<div [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
   This is the collapsible text!
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9y41x7P2ghfPvl6MjXRJ?p=preview)**

Comment: So i took your advise and used `ngbCollapse` instead of the bootstrap`s collapse, and it really does work. all i wanna know now, is there a way to give it the collapsing animation it had with the bootstrap's collapse?

Answer (score 3):

[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) highly discourages mixing Angular 2 widgets with Bootstrap's jQuery-based javascript. In fact the whole point of going with a library like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) is to *not* use Bootstrap's JS.

What you should be doing instead is to use the collapse directive: [ngbCollapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse)

Comment: I see, is there a way to achieve the animation of bootstrap's collapsing with the `ngbCollapse` component?

Comment: Animations for native directives is a work in progress at this point. The project is very active so it shouldn't take long for animations to land.